# JQuery automatically fill textfield based on select values in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

Using CF7 for wordpress, I want to populate a textfield using the option selected in a dropdown.
The expected result is that when I select a specific value in "oggetto" then the textfield "recipe" is populated with a string.
I cannot figure out why this simple jquery script doesnt work:

The script:

```
        <script text="text/javascript">
        console.log("Inside the script");
        var valore; 
        jQuery('#oggetto').change(function(){
        console.log("I'm inside");
        valore = jQuery('#oggetto').val();
        console.log(valore);
        if (valore == "Corsi") {
        console.log("Now I know what to do");
        //jQuery('#recipe').val("corsi@mydomain.com");
        document.getElementById("recipe").value = "corsi@mydomain.com"
        }
        else  {
        jQuery('#recipe').val("everybody@mydomain.com");
        }
        });
        </script>
```

The form, where "id:" defines both the fields' ids involved:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">[text* your-name placeholder "Nome e cognome *"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[email* email placeholder "Email *"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[tel phone "Telefono"]</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">[email* destinatario id:recipe]</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">[select* subject id:oggetto "Oggetto della richiesta *" "Corsi" "Informazioni generali" "Informazioni sugli eventi" "Partnership" "Altro"]</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">[textarea* message placeholder "Messaggio *"]


[submit class:btn "Invia"]</div><div class="col-xs-12"></div></div>
```

I used

```
document.getElementById("recipe").value
```

and

```
jQuery('#recipe').val("everybody@mydomain.com");
```

just after many many attempt.
But every change done inside the function seems useless because by the console.log... code execution seems to stop before the change event.
Any idea on what's wrong in my script?

Comment: Sorry... the value...
valore = jQuery('#oggetto').val();

Comment: In this fiddle my script seems to work...
https://jsfiddle.net/m460t7pu/1/

Comment: Do you have a live Wordpress site to show this issue?

Comment: You have to add something like on blur to your email field

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok, ok.
For those who get the same problem with CF7... the problem is that any js code must be AFTER the formatting code.
So... my code i right (both document.getElementById("recipe").value and jQuery('#recipe').val("everybody@mydomain.com"); ).
Simply put the script after the form, this way...